# Serving Multiple Sites via HTTPs using a web-service and Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, https

Firstly, this is a great place to learn and share new information.

Now I've an issue with hosting two websites on the same server but before describing my problem, there are some terms that I'll use henceforth to make things easier.

## **Website Setup**

- *Server OS* - CentOS 7 x64, Docker version -  18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24
- *1st Website*: example.com - hosted via Nginx (Runs as a service on the host machine and **not** via Docker Container) on port 80 (re-directs to 443) : static website with HTML / CSS code.
- *2nd Website*: http://art.example.com:8080/ : served on port 8080 via **[this](https://hub.docker.com/r/kdelfour/lychee-docker/)** Docker Image
- *SSL* - using LetsEncrypt for both the above domains.

## **Requirements**

- To serve both sites (and possibly more) via HTTPs without breaking either of them.
- This is because when I browse the 2nd website using art.example.com:8080, it works fine but if I browse the 1st website then subsequent requests to 2nd website somehow start going on HTTPs, causing the page to not load.

## **Questions**

- Can both sites (and more) be served via port **80|443** via Nginx VHosts (or any other alternative) without using a different port, i.e: **8080** for 2nd website? This is to not have any ports in the URL as mentioned above but just the domain name.
- Or, is there a way to forward traffic to the Docker service on a different port while the main main web service listens to port **80|443**? What config changes would I need to do?

I've searched on this forum as much possible but couldn't get much.

Please let me know if any more information would be required from me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: As recommended by this Docker [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/kdelfour/lychee-docker/) maintainer - [kdelfour](https://github.com/kdelfour) as well as a quick recommendation by [BretFisher](https://github.com/BretFisher), we can remake the *1st Website* as a Docker Container like the *2nd Website* and then load-balance them using [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) as a reverse proxy to manage SSL

Marking this as solved until an even better solution is found, cheers!